# Is there a way to change .NET framework version of Visual Studio 2005 to 3.5?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, frameworks

Is there a way to change .NET framework version of Visual Studio 2005 to 3.5?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way. It's probably easier to use VS 2008 for that. You might want to check the free Express edition.

Comment: 2008 can multitarget back to 2.0 if that's any help... What do you want to achieve overall?

Comment: Likely looking to get access to 3.5 features without buying VS2008. The free option is the express editions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Visual Studio 2005 only supports .NET 2.0 out-of-the-box. It can be updated to support [.NET 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=10cc340b-f857-4a14-83f5-25634c3bf043).

It is possible to compile .NET 3.5 code with a [Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/Express/), or without Visual Studio 2008 using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com) and I think the [Windows/.NET SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=F26B1AA4-741A-433A-9BE5-FA919850BDBF). However these will obviously not be integrated into Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: If you try to point to a .NET 3.0 assembly it will give you an error. It won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2005 only supports .NET 2.0. The format of the solution file (.sln) changed in Visual Studio 2008 to allow you to select the target .NET version.

Answer (score 1):

VS2008/2010 have a visual way of setting the project setting "TargetFrameworkVersion" which makes it easier, however I have found that adding the same tag to a VS2005 project will change the target framework.  You might try adding 1(one) of the following into the  section of your VS C# project.

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```